# extracting secret password from string using preg_match?

Tags: preg-match

how can I use preg_match to extract secret_password from this string?
s:6:"secret_password"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a colon-delimited string, it might be better to use `explode(':', $string)` but here is the answer using `preg_match`

```
$subject = 's:6:"secret_password"';
$pattern = '/\"[^"]+\"/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```